# Unable to create and run a python egg

Tags: python, python-3.x, egg

Consider the following directory structure

```
root
   | example_pkg
        | stuff.py
   | setup.py
```

following are the contents of `stuff.py`

```
def main():
    print("egg test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

following are the contents of `setup.py`

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="example_pkg",
    version="0.0.1",
    py_modules=['example_pkg.stuff:main']
)
```

I am creating my `egg` by running `python setup.py bdist_egg`

and then running the `egg` using the command `python dist\example_pkg-0.0.1-py3.6.egg`

However, I keep getting the following error

```
can't find '__main__' module in 'dist\\example_pkg-0.0.1-py3.6.egg'
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.

Python version : `3.6.8`

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://blog.magiksys.net/how-to-release-and-deploy-python-application

Comment: I did see this blog post. However, since I'm fairly new to python, I couldn't make much out of it. So if you could break it down for me, it'll be a great help